# What can we do to encourage more "Chen derivation" questions?

Tags: discussion

In many of their podcasts, the founders of Stack Exchange have made comments that the secret to having a successful site is in attracting expert level participation. They noted that in-depth, detailed questions were a key part of that. I believe that the question about the derivation of the Chen Formula very much fits this category of questions. But we need more of them. How an we get them?

Comment: I did answer one chen formula and it go not votes  http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/the-right-bluff-frequency/6690#6690

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is not enough traffic coming through the site at the moment.

All we can do is try and promote the site as much as possible to get more traffic on here.

Once there is more traffic more questions will come and more experts will be on hand to answer the questions.

Not really sure how to drive people to the site other than talking about it constantly at the tables or with any poker groups/ forums you are involved in.

Comment: Just having more people isn't enough though. I'm concerned that there might not be enough portion of interesting questions being asked for the expert-level players to be interested. Without them being interested, even a lot of traffic is going to result in a less-than-stellar site. I myself go through periods where the overall simplicity of the questions we do get makes me less motivated to return regularly.

Answer (score 1):

I have some expertise in SEO, and can say that talking about PokerSE on the forums is not an only way of getting more traffic.

The most efficient is asking some "mass" questions. That means: interesting to mass of people and formulated using optimal key words from search engine point of view.

For example this question:
[Poker Rooms Comparison](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/poker-rooms-comparison)

It is now on the 2nd page of Google output by term "**poker rooms comparison**".
And it will tend to get the 1st place in several months or so. And many new people will come. Because SE sites are extremely trusted and privileged by Google and because of their search engine optimized structure.

Yes, this is not solving a question of getting more PRO into poker stackexchange, but at least we will get more traffic.

**Update:**
Another issue is that poker community is very conservative. Experienced players got used to the forums where they "live" nowadays, and it is difficult to lure them out. For example 2+2 forums, or Gipsyteam (for CIS players).

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that this seems to be becoming a rather large problem. The traffic on the site is pretty low but the percentage of the questions that I am interested in looking at is pretty low. I would describe myself as an intermediate player so for players more advanced than me it I imagine there is very few posts that would be of interest.

I think that another problem is that there does tend to be low level questions but there are also lots of low level answers and comments. I have seen questions where somebody is asking about what to do in a certain spot and they get responses such as "It depends." Obviously that is true but it is hardly helpful and comments/answers such as this really clog up the site. There also sometimes seems as if there is a prejudice towards in depth analysis and especially mathematical analysis. I have seems comments such as "the maths isn't all that important" or "if you use math your play becomes predictable".

Now I realise that I have just written a few complaints about the site but I think these things really discourage advanced level users from using the site, so I think that one possible solution is to try to aggressively  oppose these comments and answers (I don't mean in an aggressive tone but just as much as possible) as much as possible. If this is coupled along with an increase in traffic then hopefully the site will go somewhere.

I really like the stack exchange format and really hope that this site can be successful but at the moment I think that it is really stalling.

Also I think that we need to get LaTex!